# Unable to understand pointers to functions in C

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I am reading "The C Programming Language" by K&R and am not able to understand the concept of pointers to functions. To explain pointers to functions it gives a program as an example, the program sorts input lines numerically instead of lexicographically if an optional argument -n is given. Here is the program:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define MAXLINES 5000     /* max #lines to be sorted */
    char *lineptr[MAXLINES];  /* pointers to text lines */
    int readlines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
    void writelines(char *lineptr[], int nlines);
    void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
    int numcmp(char *, char *);
    /*sort input lines */
    main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
      int nlines;  /*number of input lines read */
      int numeric =0;  /* 1 if numeric sort */
      if (argc>1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n")==0)
      numeric=1;
      if ((nlines= readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES))>=0)
      {
         qsort((void **) lineptr,0,nlines-1, ***(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));***
         writelines(lineptr, nlines);
         return 0;
}
      else
      {
        printf("input too big to sort\n");
        return 1;
       }


}
```

My questions are:

1) In the call to qsort why are no arguments passed of type void*(in the bold and italicized part)?

2)In the call to qsort (in the bold and italicized part), what is that (*) doing all alone, where is the function that it is dereferencing?

Can someone clarify my doubts.

Comment: Read the book 2-3 times and some other book before asking such questions.

Comment: @i486: yes, it was a dumb question.

Comment: The main problem is that this book is so ancient that it pre-dates C language standardization. Therefore some of the functions present in the book, such as `qsort`, are nowadays part of the standard library. So if you name your function `qsort` you may get a conflict with "the real qsort". The best advice here is not to read K&R since it is such an hopelessly outdated book, filled with examples in poor and sloppy style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for answering your questions 1. and 2. I think you may benefit from reading about the spiral rule:

http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html.

It can be helpful for translating seemingly complicated C statements, like function pointers, into plain English:

```
void qsort(void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

'qsort' is a function taking four parameters, returning void

parameter 0 - `lineptr` - an array of void pointers.

parameter 1 - `left` - an int.

parameter 2 - `right` - an int.

parameter 3 - `comp` - a pointer to a function that takes two arguments, each of which a void pointer, and returns an int.

Then in your call to 'qsort':

```
qsort((void **) lineptr,0,nlines-1, (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));
```

You provide exactly these necessary arguments, more specifically, let's look at the third argument:

```
(int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp)
```

The final bracket evaluates to 'numcmp' or 'stcmp'. In either case this is a function returning an int, with the only difference being the data type of the arguments passed in. Without loss of generality, let's choose 'numcmp'.

So then we have:

```
(int (*)(void*,void*))(numcmp)
```

What we have on the left hand side of 'numcmp' is then a cast, which takes care of the difference in the data types of the arguments between the functions 'numcmp' and 'strcmp'. In K&R2 it actually explains this:

"The elaborate cast of the function argument casts the arguments of the comparison function. These will generally have no effect on actual representation, but assure the compiler that all is well."

Furthermore, 'stcmp' and 'numcmp' are addresses of functions and, since they are known to be functions, the & operator is not necessary.

Comment: Because probably `numcmp` and `strcmp` are not declared with `void` pointer parameters, it is necessary to provide the cast in the `qsort` call. For example, `int numcmp(int *n1, int *n2)` must be mapped onto a function that does not have `int *` parameters but `void *` parameters. Hence the cast.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `qsort` you only pass a pointer *to the function*, you do not call the function itself. The call to `numeric` or `strcmp` happens inside the `qsort` function (which you should not declare yourself, instead include `<stdlib.h>` as shown in e.g. [this `qsort` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort), if it's the standard `qsort` you're calling).

To explain it better, lets make a small example program which shows how to use and call a function pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(const char *name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\n", name);
}

void get_name_and_greet(void (*hello_function)(const char *))
{
    char name[256];
    printf("Please enter name: ");
    scanf("%255s", name);

    hello_function(name);  // Use the function pointer
}

int main(void)
{
    get_name_and_greet(&hello);  // Pass a pointer to the function
}
```

As you can see, passing a pointer to a function is no different than passing a pointer to an `int` variable.

If you did e.g.

```
get_name_and_greet(hello("foo"));
```

you would *call* the `hello` function, and use what `hello` returns as argument to the `get_name_and_greet`. This will of course not work, as `hello` doesn't return anything, and would lead to a compilation error.

---

As for the `(int (*)(void*,void*))` part, it's a simple type-cast.

Comment: shouldn't the last line in body of get_name_and_greet() be (*hello_function)(name); ?

Comment: @Birbal Doesn't have to be. Just as functions decays to pointers to themselves (that is `hello` decays to `&hello`) they also "undecay" (in lack of a better word) to function-like objects that can be called without needing to dereference them.